# Последовательное появление

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть такой HTML код:

```
<div class="good">Текст 1</div> 
<div class="good">Текст 2</div>  
<div class="good">Текст 3</div>  
<div class="good">Текст 4</div>
```

Класс `.good` скрыт `display:none;`.

Как мне сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы этот скрипт `$("div[class^='good']").show('normal')` открывал не все блоки сразу, а последовательно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, ваша конструкция:

```
$("div[class^='good']");
```

Это просто сумасшедшее пренебрежение процессорным временем и ресурсами, используйте, пожалуйста:

```
$('.good');
```

Ну а по теме вопроса можно сделать так:

```
var $target = $('.good');
var hold = 200;

$.each($target,function(i,t){
     var $this = $(t);
     setTimeout(function(){ $this.show('normal'); },i*hold);
});
```

Я применил ещё задержку 'hold', которая даёт эффект именно последовательного открывания.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7kw82g6g/ вроде, всё скопировал, не работает. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7kw82g6g/1/
Всё работает, поместите скрипт в `$(document).ready(function(){  ... });`,
т.к. он выполняется у вас до загрузки контента страницы.

Comment: Точно, вечно с этим фидлом путаюсь из-за этого.